# How do I remove the line from the camera view?

Tags: camera

Every time I enter the camera view (numpad 0) it will enter the camera view but there is a line down the center. How do I fix it so it's back to the normal view through the rectangular lens?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line is the camera object itself. Either its width is very small or its height is very large, which is making it display as a line. The camera gets its size from the *Resolution* and *Aspect Ratio* properties in the *Dimensions* panel in the *Render* tab of the *Properties* editor:

[image]

Set your resolution to something more regular (or pick a *Render Preset* from the drop-down box) and make sure your *Aspect Ratio* is '1' for both *x* and *y*.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I'm new at this so I'm kind of just learning as I go haha